# Is it possible to call an << operator overloading function to display all object contents in a pointer array?

Tags: operator-overloading

In one of my recent projects in university, I was asked to use; Overloading the <<operator for each class to allow easier printing of objects.
The project involves storing data in an pointer array of type the class I made, to later display all its contents. In the past I did this:

```
for(int i=0; i < arrSize; i++)
       {    
         nameOfArray[i].dispAll(); // name of function that displays all the get functions
       }
```

Is it possible to the same for the <<operator? If yes, how?

I tried doing the exact same thing but instead of nameOfArray[i].dispAll() I put .<<operator, which expectedly caused an error.